# Testing backbone event-hash

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, mocha.js

I needed to apply a "special" function call in Backbone's `event-hash` where the same event listener trigger two independent methods in my Backbone view. However when checking my code coverage for this view, this particular snippet of code is un-tested.

I am using `mocha`, `chai` and `sinonjs`.

I was wondering if anyone knows how to test this particular case?

```
events: {
        "focus #new-comment": function (e) {
            this.revealButtons(e);
            this._cancelZoom(e);
        },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help ?

```
events: {
    "focus #new-comment": "_onFocusNewComment",
},

_onFocusNewComment: function (e) {
    this.revealButtons(e);
    this._cancelZoom(e);
}
```

Comment: Great, simple answer! Thanks!